# Esterification of Serine

Tags: organic-chemistry, esters, amino-acids

[image: reaction pathway]

I came across this question above, and I'm unsure about the reaction with H+(aq). The answer is that the amine group is protonated as usual, but I am not sure why H+(aq) doesn't catalyse esterification of serine with itself?

As you'll be able to tell by the question, I don't have much experience and couldn't find anything that explained this in a way I can understand (so I apologise if the question is simple!). If someone could explain what happens and why, in simple terms, I would be grateful.

Many thanks

Comment: It does not catalyse the esterification because it is not anhydrous acid conditions, any ester that forms is hydrolysed back to free acid because of the water present. You need anhydrous conditions - such as the iPrOH/H2SO4 condtions shown.

Comment: Great, that makes sense - thank you!